# I'm trying to mount a TV into a brick wall covered by 2"-2.5" of drywall... is this doable?

Tags: brick, mounting, masonry, drywall-anchor

I'm trying to mount a 39" TV that I have previously mounted (with no issues) into typical wooden studs with an arm mount. The mount uses two vertically oriented 5/16" bolts. After stopping by my local tool rental, I picked up a hammer drill and some lag shields, for which they recommended a 1/2" masonry bit. The bit was obviously too large as I cannot get the lag shield to stay in place.

So now I have a few 5" long 5/16" bolts, 5/16" lag shields, and a brick wall with somewhere between 2.25" and 2.5" of drywall covering it.

Provided that I go get the right (smaller) masonry bit, should the wall support my TV or am I fighting a losing battle? Should I buy even longer 5/16" bolts?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I would bypass the drywall and long screws and flat mount 2x4 to the brick and then attach the TV mount to the studs with 1 1/2 wood screws.  You would cutaway enough drywall to achieve a flat mount.  You might have to add a 1x4 overtop to get the proper flush or slightly proud mounting.